# Determine how assembly were invoked

Tags: .net, com

I'm writing a .NET component to be used both by other .net clients and by legacy applications via COM interop. During recearch I faced expected problem: there is no configuration in case assembly was invoked via interop.

So now I need to design a workaround for cases my component was invoked via COM (using some default configuration instead of client's). The question is - what is most convenient and correct way to determine whether the caller is COM component. Some properties or AppDomain state, probably?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not check if you have configuration instead?

Comment: Configuration is what I need. However, I always have _some_ configuration, which is inherited from machine.config. Could you suggest some handy method to do this?

Comment: System.Configuration is one big maze and its been a while since I really worked with it, but maybe you should ask anther question here something like "How do I know from where my configuration is coming from?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get a clue from Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()